# Creating a multiselect with a many-to-many relationship using roles as a foreign key

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm new with laravel and am working on a project where I need to implement a multiselect feature that allows users to select multiple roles for a specific user. The database has a many-to-many relationship between the users table and the roles table, and I'm using laravel, vueJS and InertiaJS for the implementation.

I have the following tables in my database:

**users** (id, name, email, password)
**roles** (id, name)
**role_user** (id, user_id, role_id)

I want to create a multiselect input field that displays all available roles and allows the user to select multiple roles for a user. The selected roles should be stored in the role_user table.

I'm looking for guidance on how to implement this feature without using any packages.

I have already set up the users and roles tables in the database and created the necessary models in my application. I'm struggling to figure out how to establish the relationship between the selected roles and the entity in the database and how to select multiple roles for a specific user.

**Create.vue**

```
<script setup>
import BreezeAuthenticatedLayout from '@/Layouts/Authenticated.vue';
import Button from '@/Components/Button.vue'
import { Head } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { useForm, Link } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import InputIconWrapper from '@/Components/InputIconWrapper.vue'
import Input from '@/Components/Input.vue'
import Label from '@/Components/Label.vue'
import Multiselect from '@vueform/multiselect'
defineProps({ errors: Object })
const data = useForm({
        name: '',


email: '',


password: '',
  password_confirmation: '',
    });
const submit = ()=> {
       data.post("/users");
    }
</script>

 <form @submit.prevent="submit">

          <div>
            <Label for="name" value="Name">Name</Label>
            <Input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Name"
              v-model="data.name"
              required autofocus autocomplete="name" 
              class="block w-full w-full px-4 py-2 mt-2 mb-2 border rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-blue-600"
            />
            <div v-if="errors.name" class="text-red-500">{{ errors.name}}</div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <Label for="email" value="Email">Email</Label>
            <Input
              type="email"
              placeholder="Email"
              v-model="data.email"
              required autofocus autocomplete="email" 
              class="block w-full w-full px-4 py-2 mt-2 mb-2 border rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-blue-600"
            />
            <div v-if="errors.email" class="text-red-500">{{ errors.email}}</div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <Label for="password" value="Password">Password</Label>
            <Input
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
              v-model="data.password"
              required autofocus autocomplete="password" 
              class="block w-full w-full px-4 py-2 mt-2 mb-2 border rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-blue-600"
            />
            
            <div v-if="errors.password" class="text-red-500">{{ errors.password }}</div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <Label for="password_confirmation">Confirm Password</Label>
            <Input
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
              v-model="data.password_confirmation"
              class="block w-full w-full px-4 py-2 mt-2 mb-2 border rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-blue-600"
            />
            
            <div v-if="errors.password_confirmation" class="text-red-500">{{ errors.password_confirmation }}</div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="role">Role</label>
            <multiselect
  v-model="selectedRoles"
  :options="roles"
  :multiple="true"
  placeholder="Select roles"
></multiselect>
            <div v-if="errors.password_confirmation" class="text-red-500">{{ errors.password_confirmation }}</div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex items-center mt-4">
            <Button type="submit" variant="success" size="base" class="mr-2"  >
                Add User
    </Button>

    <Button variant="danger" size="base" class="mr-2"><Link :href="route('users.index')" >
              Cancel</Link>
         
    </Button>

          </div>
          
        </form>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import Multiselect from '@vueform/multiselect';

export default {
  components: {
    Multiselect,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      roles: [],
      selectedRoles: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchRoles();
  },
  methods: {
    fetchRoles() {
      axios.get('/api/roles')
        .then(response => {
          this.roles = response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style src="@vueform/multiselect/themes/default.css"></style>
```

**User Controller**

```
public function create()
{
    return inertia('Users/Create');
}

public function store(StoreUserRequest $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->all();

    $validatedData['password'] = Hash::make($validatedData['password']);

   User::create($validatedData);

   return Redirect::route('users.index')
            ->with('message', 'User created successfully');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First thing I want to review your code why we used inertia js is used to avoid writing calls from vue or other frontend frameworks and you can directory pass data from the controller.Here your modified code

```php
 public function create()
{
    $roles = Role::all();
    return inertia('Users/Create',compact('roles'));
}

public function store(StoreUserRequest $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->all();

    $validatedData['password'] = Hash::make($validatedData['password']);

   User::create($validatedData);

   return Redirect::route('users.index')
            ->with('message', 'User created successfully');
}
```

### And you can received as props inside vue that props name that you give ***roles*** like that

Comment: How can I implement in vue? for multiple selection

Comment: Here are where you can reference from this blog https://www.vuescript.com/best-multiple-select/